# Create google place search api with distance finder

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm creating a website where I want to implement an google-map API with near by place search, find distance, and show place according to the distance.

Still now I just created a map and used google place search api.
The work I have done so for [link here](http://plnkr.co/edit/05Bizqh6FeHdR5jLtGWb?p=preview)

I just want to create a map somewhat like this [`page`](https://housing.com/in/buy/projects/page/32839-wings-royal-by-venkat-estates-in-thanisandra?f=eyJhcGFydG1lbnRfdHlwZXMiOls1XSwicG9seSI6eyJpZCI6Ijc0N2JlMTNmZTQ3Y2I4YWUxNGMzIiwiYnVmZmVyIjpmYWxzZX0sImxvY3QiOiJwb2x5In0=)

Comment: Show us what you have done so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try this

```
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>nearby</title>

<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false'></script>
<script src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>

</head>


 <body>
 <div id="gmap_canvas"></div>
 <div class="actions">
  <div class="button">
    <label for="gmap_type">Type:</label>
    <select id="gmap_type">
      <option value="art_gallery" onclick="findPlaces();" >art_gallery</option>
      <option value="atm" onclick="findPlaces()" >atm</option>
      <option value="bank" onclick="findPlaces()" >bank</option>
      <option value="bar" onclick="findPlaces()" >bar</option>
      <option value="cafe" onclick="findPlaces()" >cafe</option>
      <option value="food" onclick="findPlaces()" >food</option>
      <option value="hospital" onclick="findPlaces()" >hospital</option>
      <option value="police" onclick="findPlaces()" >police</option>
      <option value="store" onclick="findPlaces()" >store</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    <label for="gmap_radius">Radius:</label>
    <select id="gmap_radius">
      <option value="500"  onclick="findPlaces()">500</option>
      <option value="1000" onclick="findPlaces()" >1000</option>
      <option value="1500" onclick="findPlaces()" >1500</option>
      <option value="5000" onclick="findPlaces()" >5000</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" id="lat" name="lat" value="51.5" />
  <input type="hidden" id="lng" name="lng" value="-0.126" />
  <div id="button1" class="button" onclick="findPlaces(); return false;">Search</div>
</div>
<table id="Display" class="table table-striped">
  <tr>
    <th>Name Of Place</th>
    <th id="city_header">Distance From Selected Place (in km)</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

js

```
var geocoder;
var map;
var markers = Array();
var infos = Array();
var datas= Array();
var sortS= Array();
var TempA=Array();
var sortN= Array();

var min=1000;
var minNam='sa';
var myJsonString='';
function initialize() {
    // prepare Geocoder
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    // set initial position (New York)
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.5, -0.126);

    var myOptions = { // default map options
         zoom: 16,
      center: myLatlng,
      scrollwheel: false,
      panControl: true,
      streetViewControl: true,
      mapTypeControl: true,
      overviewMapControl: true,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      styles:     [{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":    [{"color":"#444444"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"color":"#f2f2f2"}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":45}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"transit","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"color":"#46bcec"},{"visibility":"on"}]}]
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap_canvas'), myOptions);
}

// clear overlays function
function clearOverlays() {
    if (markers) {
        for (i in markers) {
            markers[i].setMap(null);
        }
        markers = [];
        infos = [];
    }
}

// clear infos function
function clearInfos() {
    if (infos) {
        for (i in infos) {
            if (infos[i].getMap()) {
                infos[i].close();
            }
        }
    }
}



// find custom places function
function findPlaces() {
$('#Display').find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
    // prepare variables (filter)
var type = document.getElementById('gmap_type').value;
var radius = document.getElementById('gmap_radius').value;


var lat = document.getElementById('lat').value;
var lng = document.getElementById('lng').value;
var cur_location = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

// prepare request to Places
var request = {
    location: cur_location,
    radius: radius,
    types: [type]
};


// send request
service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.search(request, createMarkers);

}

// create markers (from 'findPlaces' function)
function createMarkers(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {

        // if we have found something - clear map (overlays)
    clearOverlays();

    // and create new markers by search result
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        createMarker(results[i]);
    }

  //   console.log(datas+'datas');
       myJsonString = JSON.stringify(datas);

parse( $.parseJSON(myJsonString));
      console.log(sortS);
      TempA = sortS.slice();
      console.log(TempA);
      sortS.sort();
           console.log(sortS);
         console.log(sortN);

       for (var i = 0; i < sortS.length; i++) {

           console.log(sortN[TempA.indexOf(sortS[i])]);
         $('#Display').append('<tr><td>'+sortN[TempA.indexOf(sortS[i])]+'</td><td>'+sortS[i]+'</td></tr>');
//parseSort($.parseJSON(myJsonString),sortS[i]);


     //console.log(sortN[TempA.indexOf(sortS[i])]);
    }
  datas=[];
  myJsonString='';
               sortS= [];
 TempA=[];
 sortN= [];
   //   c
    } else if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
    alert('Sorry, nothing is found');
}
}

// creare single marker function
function createMarker(obj) {

    // prepare new Marker object
    var mark = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: obj.geometry.location,
        map: map,
        title: obj.name
    });
    // alert(obj.name);
   var lat=document.getElementById('lat').value;
   var long=document.getElementById('lng').value;

  var p1 = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,long);
var p2 = new google.maps.LatLng(obj.geometry.location.lat(),obj.geometry.location.lng());

  google.maps.LatLng.prototype.distanceFrom = function(latlng) {
  var lat = [this.lat(), latlng.lat()]
  var lng = [this.lng(), latlng.lng()]
  var R = 6378137;
  var dLat = (lat[1]-lat[0]) * Math.PI / 180;
  var dLng = (lng[1]-lng[0]) * Math.PI / 180;
  var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
  Math.cos(lat[0] * Math.PI / 180 ) * Math.cos(lat[1] * Math.PI / 180 ) *
  Math.sin(dLng/2) * Math.sin(dLng/2);
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
  var d = R * c;
  return Math.round(d);
}
obj.geometry.location.lng());
var dist = p2.distanceFrom(p1);

  var distn=dist;
  var dost=distn+(distn <1 ? "m" : "km")
  datas.push({ place:obj.name,Distance:distn});

    markers.push(mark);

// prepare info window
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: '<img src="' + obj.icon + '" /><font style="color:#000;">' + obj.name + 
    '<br />Rating: ' + obj.rating + '<br />Vicinity: ' + obj.vicinity + '</font>'
});

// add event handler to current marker
google.maps.event.addListener(mark, 'click', function() {
    clearInfos();
    infowindow.open(map,mark);
});



infos.push(infowindow);

console.log(myJsonString);

}

console.log(myJsonString+'sa');
console.log(datas+'datas');
var v=0;

  function parse(obj) {

    // Do something.

    $.each(obj, function(idx,obj1) {


    if(typeof obj1 =='object')
    {  parse(obj1);

    }else{



       if(idx==='place')
      { 
        sortN.push(obj1);
      }
      if(idx==='Distance')
      { 
        sortS.push(obj1);
      }
    }

});
}


  function  parseSort(obj,i) {

    $.each(obj, function(idx,obj1) {

    if(typeof obj1 =='object')
    {  parseSort(obj,i);

    }else{

        alert(idx+":"+obj1); 
      var previous='';
      if(idx==='place')
      { 
       previous=obj1;
      }
      if(idx==='Distance')
      { 
         if(i===obj1)
      { 

        alert("here");
      //  $('#Display').append('<tr><td>'+obj1+'</td><td>'+previous+'</td></tr>');

          }

          }
        }

    });
  }

//parse(datas);

function SortF(){

  var table = $('#Display');

$('#facility_header, #city_header')
    .wrapInner('<span title="sort this column"/>')
    .each(function(){

        var th = $(this),
            thIndex = th.index(),
            inverse = false;

        th.click(function(){

            table.find('td').filter(function(){

                return $(this).index() === thIndex;

            }).sortElements(function(a, b){

                return $.text([a]) > $.text([b]) ?
                    inverse ? -1 : 1
                    : inverse ? 1 : -1;
            }, function(){
                // parentNode is the element we want to move
                return this.parentNode;          
            });
            inverse = !inverse;     
        });                
    });
 }
```

some css

```
        #gmap_canvas {
      height: 300px;
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
    float:left;
  }
  .actions {
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      bottom: 30px;
      padding: 10px;
      float:left;
      right: 30px;
      z-index: 2;

      border-top: 1px solid #abbbcc;
      border-left: 1px solid #a7b6c7;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #a1afbf;
      border-right: 1px solid #a7b6c7;
      -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
      -moz-border-radius: 12px;
      border-radius: 12px;
  }
  #Display{
    float:left;
          width:75%;

        }
        .actions label {
      display: block;
      margin: 2px 0 5px 10px;
      text-align: left;
  }
  .actions input, .actions select {
      width: 85%;
  }
   .button {
      background-color: #d7e5f5;
      background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #d7e5f5), color-stop(100%, #cbe0f5));
      background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #d7e5f5, #cbe0f5);
      background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #d7e5f5, #cbe0f5);
      background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #d7e5f5, #cbe0f5);
      background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #d7e5f5, #cbe0f5);
      background-image: linear-gradient(top, #d7e5f5, #cbe0f5);
      border-top: 1px solid #abbbcc;
      border-left: 1px solid #a7b6c7;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #a1afbf;
      border-right: 1px solid #a7b6c7;
      -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
      -moz-border-radius: 12px;
      border-radius: 12px;
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 white;
      -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 white;
      box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 white;
      color: #1a3e66;
      font: normal 11px "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans",Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
      line-height: 1;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
      padding: 6px 0 7px 0;
      text-align: center;
      text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #fff;
      width: 150px;
  }
  .button:hover {
      background-color: #ccd9e8;
      background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #ccd9e8), color-stop(100%, #c1d4e8));
      background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ccd9e8, #c1d4e8);
      background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ccd9e8, #c1d4e8);
      background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ccd9e8, #c1d4e8);
      background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ccd9e8, #c1d4e8);
      background-image: linear-gradient(top, #ccd9e8, #c1d4e8);
      border-top: 1px solid #a1afbf;
      border-left: 1px solid #9caaba;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #96a3b3;
      border-right: 1px solid #9caaba;
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 #f2f2f2;
      -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 #f2f2f2;
      box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 #f2f2f2;
      color: #163659;
      cursor: pointer;
  }
  .button:active {
      border: 1px solid #8c98a7;
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px 2px #abbccf, 0 0 1px 0 #eeeeee;
      -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px 2px #abbccf, 0 0 1px 0 #eeeeee;
      box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px 2px #abbccf, 0 0 1px 0 #eeeeee;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

For the distance, I used the Google Geocoder API for a project I had.

Here is a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/AdrielD/e02ade562c847c474eaa) I made, you can translate that on whatever language you are using. Basically, call this URL:

"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=[YOUR_ADDRESS_STRING]"

And the API will return a bunch of information. The most important is Latitude and Longitude. Than, you can use those in [Haversine Formula](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Haversine_formula). The formula takes two points (their latitude and longitude) and calculates the distance between those points.

Find more at: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro

I did not implement the map markers or anything else, but I hope this could help you with the distances.

Comment: This is not the same, I'm looking for but I will give you the bounty if no one give the answer. Thanks